# Change width and height depending the screen size with CSS

Tags: css

I've a div containing some item.

Depending the screen size how can I change the width and height of these elements ?

So for example, for `min-width: 576px` I would need 2 squares on the same line

```
<style>
    @media (min-width: 576px) {  
        a.el {
            width: 50%;
            height: 50%;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {  
        a.el {
            width: 25%;
            height: 25%;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 992px) {  
        a.el {
            width: 10%;
            height: 10%;
        }
    }
</style>


<div>
    <a href="" class="el">Link</a>
    <a href="" class="el">Link</a>
    <a href="" class="el">Link</a>
    <a href="" class="el">Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You will need to set your `a` to `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` in order for them to have `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set your `a` to `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` in order for them to have `width` and `height`, BUT height percentages won't work unless your parent element has a height.

You could use `display: flex;` (flexbox) on the parent element to align all your `.el` on one line and `flex-wrap: wrap;` to allow them to wrap when they need to (`width: 50%;` when there are more than 2 items).

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve with the `height` property here because your sizes get smaller as your screen gets larger, BUT if you define a height to `.parent` like: `.parent { height: 100vh; }` you will see that your `.el` will have `height`.

```css
/* for borders and padding to be included in width sizing */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* if you want your .el to be on the same line when  */
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

a.el {
    border: 1px solid;
} 

@media (min-width: 576px) {  
    a.el {
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {  
    a.el {
        width: 25%;
        height: 25%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {  
    a.el {
        width: 10%;
        height: 10%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <a href="" class="el">Link</a>
    <a href="" class="el">Link</a>
    <a href="" class="el">Link</a>
    <a href="" class="el">Link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex to accomplish this in your media query.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  #container {
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
  }
  a.el {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 45%;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #container {
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
  }
  a.el {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 45%;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #container {
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
  }
  a.el {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 20%;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <a href="" class="el">Link</a>
  <a href="" class="el">Link</a>
  <a href="" class="el">Link</a>
  <a href="" class="el">Link</a>
</div>
```